# php NumberFormatter:parse issue

Tags: php, parsing, numberformatter

```
<?php
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
$num = "1 234 567,891";
echo $fmt->parse($num)."\n";
echo $fmt->parse($num, NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT32)."\n";
?>
```

It is returning only the first character i.e, 1 . Expected output is 1234567.89

Answer (score 0):

For me, it outputs `1234567.891` and `1234567` - so it works as expected. However, according to [a comment in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php#109323), this depends on the used versions.

One more guess is that `1 234 567,891` is valid in `fr_FR`, but not in `de_DE`.